# Inserting new div with Id inside existing div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want create div inside another div using. Please tell me where am going wrong.

```js
   window.onload =function() {
    var child = document.createElement('div');
    child.id = 'blockid';
    child.className = 'blockclass';
    
    var s = document.getElementById('parent');
    s.appendChild(child); 
    document.getElementById("blockid").innerHTML = "hi";
    }
```

```html
<div id="parent">Test</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. In the code you shared `blockid` is inserted inside `parent`. Do you expect `parent` to cinain only the div and not `Hi` anymore ?

Comment: @ ANI: That code should be fine (although you don't need the last `document.getElementById`, just use `child`). So we need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/czzhkx26/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be getting mislead by how the result looks:

```
Test
hi
```

That makes it look like they're stacked, but they're not, your code is working fine. The second div is *inside* the first, after the text.

Adding borders and padding can make that clearer:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.id = 'blockid';
  child.className = 'blockclass';

  var s = document.getElementById('parent');
  s.appendChild(child);
  document.getElementById("blockid").innerHTML = "hi";
};
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px;
}
#blockid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">Test</div>
```

Note, though, that you don't need the `document.getElementById` at the end, you can use `child`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.id = 'blockid';
  child.className = 'blockclass';

  var s = document.getElementById('parent');
  s.appendChild(child);
  child.innerHTML = "hi"; // <== Changed
};
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px;
}
#blockid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">Test</div>
```